# Why did Jude use the word “common” to describe salvation in Jude 1:3?

Tags: jude

It seems Jude 1:3 was describing "salvation" as something that everybody could easily obtain and/or something that everyone already knows about.

> **Jude 1:3** Beloved, while I was giving all diligence to write unto you of our ***common*** salvation, I was constrained to write unto you
>   exhorting you to contend earnestly for the faith which was once for
>   all delivered unto the saints. **(ASV)**

There does not seem to be an agreement when Paul says:

> ... work out your salvation with fear and trembling" 
>   **(Philippians 2:12)**.

Comment: Thank your for this comment. My concern is that Jude is envisioning salvation not necessarily as something accomplished as a team and/or demanding that each person work for their individual salvation; but that he is envisioning "our costly" salvation as something that is not worth the candle. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. And welcome to the site.

Comment: It's a pleasure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plese have a look at different other translations too. For instance the ESV (likewise ISV, GNT, NLT, etc.) is rendering:

**Jude 1:3**

> ... the salvation **we share**... (**ESV**)

for

> ... τῆς κοινῆς ἡμῶν σωτηρίας ...

The greek "κοινῆς" (*koines*) means "**common**" in the sense of something being shared among a number of individuals, of something belonging to a certain numebr of individuals in the same time. It does not mean that something is easy. For more, please have a look [here](https://studybible.info/strongs/G2839)

As it is not always easy to share something, there is no contradiciton between Jude 1:3 and Philippians 2:12.

Comment: For an example, the Koine Greek has this name because was a language spoken by all the major western civilizations, starting from the Alexander the Great's age. Koine Greek was  the lingua franca of that epoca, really. Was a language common to a very vast amount of people.

Answer (score 2):

The word translated "common" is the Greek "koinos", an adjective which can take any of the following meanings (see Analytical Lexicon of NT Words by Friberg et al, Souter, etc)

- as belonging equally to several, mutual, communal, in common (eg Acts 2:44)
- not consecrated, common or ordinary (eg, Rev 21:27)...
- defiled (ceremonially) unacceptable (Acts 10:14)…

In the case of Jude 3, I suggest that the obvious meaning is #1 above meaning that which we hold communally, or mutually.  I do not believe that Paul here or anywhere else suggests that our salvation is anything but special as your reference in Phil 2:12 confirms.  However, it is held as something in-common with all Christians who trust in Jesus.

Comment: I've posted a question on meta regarding your use of the term "ANLEX" on this site because, as I've said before I don't think it is appropriate:  https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/is-anlex-a-legitimate-abbreviation-to-use-on-this-site  Please remember Paul's exhortation:  "If then I do not know the meaning of the language, I will be to the one who speaks a barbarian, and the one who speaks will be a barbarian to me."

Answer (score 0):

Salvation touches the triune nature of man. Salvation touches our spirit, soul and body.

When you receive Jesus you receive eternal life, but your mind (soul) is constantly being renewed and experiences salvation every time the Holy Spirit brings illumination and healing. Your body likewise experiences salvation when you experience the resurrection power and healings as they did in the book of Acts.

Jude is referring to Jews who try and rob Christians from the anchor of our faith which is Christ. The fact that we have already passed from death onto life by recognising and receiving Christ as our personal Saviour (Messiah).

Now Paul is referring to a more mature sonship position of Salvation and the end goal of our faith which is the glorification of Jesus Christ through the power of God through us (healing, deliverance and manifestation of all the promises of God). This part of salvation is not easy as its often a battle and its not automatic as its relationship based.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction here because in the verse that speaks of common salvation, the reference is made to a state of being saved, which all Christians should attain first, i.e. the presence of the Holy Spirit inside and a clear conscience so as not to drive the Spirit away (see 1 Tim. 1:19, Eph. 2:8; also see how the Spirit **is** salvation/eternal life in John 6:63), because it is written that we cannot do Gospel's prescriptions right "without Him" (John 15:5).

As for the second verse that speaks of working out the salvation, it refers to the kind of salvation that one doesn't die with (if a Christian dies with the Spirit, he goes straight to heaven, see John 6:47), but which one receives at the Judgement (to Judgement go all who die without the Spirit -- see the same John 6:47, plus Revelation 14:1) if he/she had done certain kind of **works** (here is where "to work out the salvation" comes from) and didn't trust in them for salvation when he/she died (see Matthew 25 judgement where those who ministered to Christians in need during their life receive salvation at the Judgement; also see the parable of the rich fool, where the grain symbolizes good works one had done during life, and where works are a fruit/creation of our hands in a way; after this parable note that God always minds it when we place our faith in something other than Himself -- see countless example from O.T.). Please also note that this is different from the place where Paul speaks of the time when each man's works will be tested, and those whose works do not "burn", receive a reward. Here Paul speaks of rewards that all the saved receive **after** they make it to heaven.

Answer (score 0):

In his letter he is addressing his ***fellow belevers*** thus they hold in "common" deliverance from sin and death via the Ransom of Christ and hold to a heavenly hope as "called" ones, see in verse 1.